# How to Use 1st Class Properties and Methods in 2nd Class?

Tags: php, object, scope

I have two classes. Lets call them 'Class_A' and 'Class_B'. I want to use 'Class_A' properties and methods in 'Class B'. Like this...

```
$a = new Class_A;


class Class_B {

    function __construct() {

        $a->foo = 2;

        $a->magic();

    }

}
```

Of course, it do not work. What is the best practice to deal with it?

- 'global' keyword?
- Make properties and methods of 'Class_A' static?
- Another way...?

Comment: It would all depend on what you are actually trying to accomplish.  Each method has its own benefits and drawbacks. You could use static members, inheritance, or pass Class_A to Class_B as a parameter.  It just depends on what you need to do.

Comment: I am creating tiny MVC framework. 'Class_A' would stand for 'view', but 'Class_B' for 'controller'.
I used static members to do it, but it seems that almost every other MVC framework use 'dependency injection'.

Comment: I wonder what's better for my situation.

P.S. Sorry for double-post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dependency injection](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection)

```
$a = new Class_A();

class Class_B {
    function __construct($x) {
          $x->foo = 2;
          $x->magic();
    }
} 

$b = new Class_B($a);
```

Comment: It'll be a pleasure to meet you too Gordon. I've not been to an unConference before, so I'm not sure quite what to expect... but hoping to introduce a few people to the benefits of working with "real" Excel files in PHP :)

Comment: I'd expect fun and socializing first and foremost. The session timeframes are usually too small to get more than an overview on a topic anyway. It's meeting the people that's nice :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need an instance of class `Class_A`, then pass it to class `Class_B`s constructor:

```
class Class_B {
    function __construct($a) {
        $a->foo = 2;
        $a->magic();
    }
}

$a_instance = new Class_A();

$b = new Class_B($a_instance);
```

If class `Class_A` does not need to be instantiated in order to perform its tasks, define properties and methods as static instead and call them with `Class_A::method();`

Avoid `global`s. If `Class_B` *is* also a `Class_B` (e.g. a banana is a fruit), then you probably go better with inheritance.